# Why is Directory.build.props ignored for c# console project

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I am trying to include Directory.build.props file as I want to have one place to change the version of all the projects.

If I build solution using Visual Studio the properties inside Director.build.props file are correctly embedded inside the built exe file.
If I use the **dotnet** **build** command, the exe file does not have the required properties embedded.What I observed is that the dll files have correct properties embedded using CLI command as well using Visual Studio.

The Directory.build.props file is located at the root of the solution (I've tried putting it at the root of the project and the same thing happens).
This is the Directory.build.props file that I'm using

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Company>Company</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright</Copyright>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0</FileVersion>    
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing some configuration, and why are dlls successfully embedded with properties while the exe file is not?

Comment: Do you call `dotnet build` on windows or linux/mac?

Comment: I call it on windows

Comment: I seen, on *nix the file must be named `Directory.Build.props` (upper case B) because that is what MSBuild is looking for. Can you reproduce this with an example project and upload a binary log (`dotnet build -bl` creates an `msbuild.binlog`). what does `dotnet --version` print?

Comment: You can find the example [here](https://github.com/hbagarich/netcore-build-props-example)
I've uploaded the binlog to the same repo and you can find it [here](https://github.com/hbagarich/netcore-build-props-example/blob/master/ConsoleBuildPropsExampleApp/msbuild.binlog)

Comment: In the binlog, i can see the attributes being correctly set for both projects (company, copyright) although the compiler is not invoked because the project is considered up to date (a clean would change that). Can you be more specific on how to reproduce this issue? (e.g. `dotnet clean; dotnet build -bl; assembly xy should have company yz`)

Comment: The **.dll** files have attributes set correctly, but the produced **.exe** file does not and that is a problem for me. Steps to reproduce is to build the solution using the **dotnet build**. I have tried a clean build as well but the result is always the same.

Comment: Are you sure that a VS build created an .exe file with attributes? In both cases, the .exe is a copied and modified prebuilt bootstrapper executable. In 3.0 there is a build step that can updated embedded resources though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the attributes on the apphost executable is supported in the 3.0 SDK. Make sure you have at least the 3.0.100 SDK (i tested .NET Core 3.0 Preview 5) installed.

Answer (score 12):

Credits go to @Martin Ullrich, but on *nix the file should indeed be called `Directory.Build.props` (proper casing) otherwise it will be ignored.